# How do I know that my Application loads the correct assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have an assembly that is used to verify the security of my Application such as the license.
How do I grant that every time my Application calls the verification method, this is being loaded from the correct assembly?
I want to prevent that someone creates a fake assembly to bypass these verifications.

By adding a `.snk` to get a Strong Named Key, will this solve my problem?

E.g. If my application uses `MySecurity.dll`, if someone else creates a assembly with the same name and override it in the `bin` folder, will my application know that this is not the correct assembly?

I am worried because our solution uses two kinds of verification, local using a **public certificate** for the license file, and online (if has internet connection). But any of these can be bypassed easily.

[image]

Comment: The strong naming mechanism exists for tprecisely this case.

Comment: @Gusdor no it is not. If it was the end user would not be able to [disable it via the command line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/securitytools/2009/12/30/how-to-turn-off-strong-name-validation/). Strong naming exists to prevent accedental name collisions of assemblies from multiple vendors.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Integrity is specifically called out in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/create-and-use-strong-named-assemblies

Comment: That is about integrity of the file by modifacation of a 3rd party without the end users concent. It does not protect from a end user attempting to replace or modify the file

Answer (score -1):

You can hard code the hash string of that dll file in your code and check it at run-time (maybe in a timer)

Also you need to protect your assemblies with some thing like this [Eazfuscator.NET](https://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net)

Comment: Authenticode signing would be the best way to check it. On your assembly.load event check that the assembly is signed by the expected certificate. A note to the OP authenticode and strong name signing are two different mechanisms.